# Sending data via Socket.BeginSend/EndSend isn't flushing the buffer?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have a class that handles communication to and from a client connected to my server. I am able to process the packets sent to me from the telnet clients without much of an issue.

#### The client connection class

```
namespace Mud.Engine.Components.WindowsServer
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using Mud.Engine.Runtime.Game.Character;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the players networking state.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class PlayerConnectionState
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The size of the buffer that will hold data sent from the client
        /// </summary>
        private readonly int bufferSize;

        /// <summary>
        /// A temporary collection of incomplete messages sent from the client. These must be put together and processed.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly List<string> currentData = new List<string>();

        /// <summary>
        /// What the last chunk of data sent from the client contained.
        /// </summary>
        private string lastChunk = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Instances a new PlayerConnectionState.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="player">An instance of a Player type that will be performing network communication</param>
        /// <param name="currentSocket">The Socket used to communicate with the client.</param>
        /// <param name="bufferSize">The storage size of the data buffer</param>
        public PlayerConnectionState(IPlayer player, Socket currentSocket, int bufferSize)
        {
            this.Player = player;
            this.CurrentSocket = currentSocket;

            this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
            this.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Player instance associated with this state.
        /// </summary>
        public IPlayer Player { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Socket for the player associated with this state.
        /// </summary>
        public Socket CurrentSocket { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the data currently in the network buffer
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets if the current network connection is in a valid state.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsConnectionValid
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CurrentSocket != null && this.CurrentSocket.Connected;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts listening for network communication sent from the client to the server
        /// </summary>
        public void StartListeningForData()
        {
            this.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            this.CurrentSocket.BeginReceive(this.Buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveData), null);
            this.Player.CommandManager.CommandCompleted += this.HandleCommandExecutionCompleted;
        }

        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            this.CurrentSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.CompleteMessageSending), null);
        }

        private void CompleteMessageSending(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            this.CurrentSocket.EndSend(asyncResult);
        }

        private void HandleCommandExecutionCompleted(object sender, CommandCompletionArgs e)
        {
            this.SendMessage($"{e.Command} executed.\r\n");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Receives the input data from the user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="result">The result.</param>
        private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            // If we are no longer in a valid state, dispose of the connection.
            if (!this.IsConnectionValid)
            {
                this.CurrentSocket?.Dispose();
                return;
            }

            int bytesRead = this.CurrentSocket.EndReceive(result);
            if (bytesRead == 0 || !this.Buffer.Any())
            {
                this.StartListeningForData();
                return;
            }

            ProcessReceivedData(bytesRead);
            this.StartListeningForData();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Process the data we received from the client.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bytesRead"></param>
        private void ProcessReceivedData(int bytesRead)
        {
            // Encode our input string sent from the client
            this.lastChunk = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            // Temporary to avoid handling the telnet negotiations for now. 
            // This needs to be abstracted out in to a negotation class that will parse, send and receive negotiation requests.
            if (this.Buffer.First() == 255)
            {
                return;
            }

            // If the previous chunk did not have a new line feed, then we add this message to the collection of currentData.
            // This lets us build a full message before processing it.
            if (!lastChunk.Contains("\r\n"))
            {
                // Add this to our incomplete data stash and read again.
                this.currentData.Add(lastChunk);
                return;
            }

            // This message contained at least 1 new line, so we split it and process per line.
            List<string> messages = lastChunk.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

            foreach (string line in this.PruneReceivedMessages(messages))
            {
                this.Player.CommandManager.ProcessCommandForCharacter(this.Player, line);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs through the messages collection and prepends data from a previous, incomplete, message
        /// and updates the internal message tracking state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="messages"></param>
        private List<string> PruneReceivedMessages(List<string> messages)
        {            
            // Append the first line to the incomplete line given to us during the last pass if one exists.
            if (this.currentData.Any() && messages.Any())
            {
                messages[0] = string.Format("{0} {1}", string.Join(" ", this.currentData), messages[0]);
                this.currentData.Clear();
            }

            // If we have more than 1 line and the last line in the collection does not end with a line feed
            // then we add it to our current data so it may be completed during the next pass. 
            // We then remove it from the lines collection because it can be infered that the remainder will have
            // a new line due to being split on \n.
            if (messages.Count > 1 && !messages.Last().EndsWith("\r\n"))
            {
                this.currentData.Add(messages.Last());
                messages.Remove(messages.Last());
            }

            return messages;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is really focused on the following methods:

```
    public void StartListeningForData()
    {
        this.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        this.CurrentSocket.BeginReceive(this.Buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveData), null);
        this.Player.CommandManager.CommandCompleted += this.HandleCommandExecutionCompleted;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        this.CurrentSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.CompleteMessageSending), null);
    }

    private void CompleteMessageSending(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        this.CurrentSocket.EndSend(asyncResult);
    }

    private void HandleCommandExecutionCompleted(object sender, CommandCompletionArgs e)
    {
        this.SendMessage($"{e.Command} executed.\r\n");
    }
```

When a message is processed by my stuff, it creates a new CommandCompletionArg, passes it the command string, and sends it along to the event handler. When the `HandleCommandExecutionCompleted` handler is invoked, the `e.Command` property does hold the data that I sent in via the Telnet client. I would expect to see my command echo'd back to me.

Enter: "Hello World"
Expected Result: "Hello World executed."
Result: " executed."

As I type additional commands, the additional commands are sent along with the previous command results over again. It also looks like that if I send in a command string longer than the string I am echoing back, it adds the string to the end. You can see the oddity in the screenshots, on both Windows and OS X.

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand why when I debug, I can see that e.Command actually has data, but it never sends it back to the client. It only sends "executed".

[image: OS X]
[image: Windows]

If it helps any, the [code is open source and available](https://github.com/scionwest/muddesigner) to view in its entirety. You can clone it from GitHub and run the Desktop.Server.App project. The port you connect to is 5000.

Comment: There is no need to use an async send.  Doesn't provide any performance improvements.  I would just use SendMessage instead.  It is also bad to use a combination of sync write and async write in same application.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I'm not using sync write anywhere. In both my server and the client connection code, I am using the Begin/End async pattern.

Comment: Changing it to Just `CurrentSocket.Send` does not solve the problem either. I am still getting my echo multiplied with each message sent back to the client

Comment: Where are you sending bytesRead?

Comment: I'm not doing anything with the bytesRead value returned to me. Should I be?

Comment: You said : "I would expect to see my command echo'd back to me".  How does command get sent back?  Telnet doesn't automatically echo back command.  It only has a local echo setting, not remote echo.

Comment: Sorry, I chose the wrong terminology. What I meant was that when I send a message from my telnet client to the server, my server for the moment is taking the message it received and sending it right back to the client with "executed" appended to it. That is what I meant by echoing. I am just re-pushing the message I just received back to the client. The original message does not show up, but the "executed" content does. I check the string before I encode it, and the original message is included with it. I'm not sure why it's not sent when I call `Send` or `BeginSend`.

Comment: Telnet uses TCP as transport layer.  You can receive datagrams with zero bytes especially if keep-alive option is being used.  It is possible that you are closing the connection before the message is getting received.  I don't like closing connection after each message isent.  If you do close connection after each message you have to wait until the message is fully received.  So I recommend sending a return character at end of message.  Then have the receiver wait until return is received before processing the received message.

Comment: I'm not closing the connection. The socket is left open until the server shuts down, or the client disconnects. The server periodically scans a collection of sockets and checks if any of them are still valid, and if not, disposes and removes of them. During my testing where this issue occurs, the socket was never closed/reopened.

Comment: Put a break point on the return statements in ReceiveData and see if you are returning before reading the data.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The code above is my server code. `ReceiveData` is called when it receives data from the client; `SendMessage` is what is giving me the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this after learning a little more about special characters. The message coming back from the telnet client had \r appended to it. I was just forwarding the content from the server right back to the client, causing the client to move the cursor back to the beginning of the line and overwrite the original message with the "executed"

The content sent to the client was `Hello World\r executed.\r\n`. After removing the \r at the end of the content i received from the client, I was able to send it back to the client as `Hello World executed\r\n'. Problem solved.

I was also subscribing to the same event, multiple times.

```
    public void StartListeningForData()
    {
        this.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        this.CurrentSocket.BeginReceive(this.Buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveData), null);
        this.Player.CommandManager.CommandCompleted += this.HandleCommandExecutionCompleted;
    }
```

The event handler would call `SendMessage`

```
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        this.CurrentSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.CompleteMessageSending), this.CurrentSocket);
    }

    private void CompleteMessageSending(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        var client = asyncResult.AsyncState as Socket;

        client.EndSend(asyncResult);
    }

    private void HandleCommandExecutionCompleted(object sender, CommandCompletionArgs e)
    {
        this.SendMessage($"{e.Command} executed.\r\n");
    }
```

Thus causing my duplication of the messages being sent to the client.